# How to stop Jupyter (ipython 3) and LATEX from rendering \phi and \varphi differently

Tags: python, latex, ipython, jupyter

In the snippet below from a Jupyter/ipython notebook, the first cell is a code cell, while the second is a markdown cell:

[image]

(NOTE: You need to press **TAB** in the code cell for Jupyter to render the greek letter)

As you can see, LATEX and Jupyter swap the phi and varphi characters. Probably neither is "correct" (could be wrong about that), but my experience leads me to believe that the LATEX interpretation is the more accepted one.

Is there a simple way to swap the renderings that Jupyter is using? If not, how about a way to swap the renderings that LATEX uses?

EDIT: for the curious, this is important because in some civil engineering disciplines, both symbols are used and mean different things.

Comment: There are two issues here: the symbols themselves are not correct, i.e., the first example has no correct mapping to the corresponding character. The other difference is that they're not in italics. The LaTeX output (italics) is the more accepted one, but you could always define with LaTeX `\newcommand{}[]{}` a non-italic version of the letters. It’d be more elegant to change the Jupyter interpretation, though.

Comment: @Informagic the italics issue isn't an issue, imo. the first example is a code input cell, and italics is never used in that type of cell.